# How to display text diagonally and vertically in applet

Tags: java, applet

What is the best way to display text diagonally and vertically in a `JApplet`. I want to show the string variable.

Example of a diagonal format can be found [here](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3aANd9GcT5zB32LNw5NG34oiKCf7wau1kHM57RjHDeMIH3C_Bc1tn9hsX3).

Example of a vertical format:

```
V
E
R
T
I
C
A
L
```

Comment: What have you tried? Also marking your post as urgent is of no concern to `SO` users

Comment: i have tried to use the Transform method, but that hasnt been useful in creating the diagonal text as it just displays it in the "slope" format which rotates the text aswell

Answer (score 0):

There are components that do this naturally.

1. You could try using a JTextArea. Just add a new line after every character for vertical. Then you can add multiple spaces before every line for diagonal. Actually text area support letter wrapping so you could use a monospaced font and create the textarea with a single column and it should do the vertical for you.
2. You could use a [Text Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/04/02/text-icon/) for vertical. Then maybe customize the code for diagonal to add a gap for every letter.

Comment: the thing is, the text is meant to be displayed on a GUI , so whenever the user enters the text and chooses which style, the text then appears as the style chosen which is then displayed on the GUI itself.

Comment: Oh, okay, thank you very much, i'm still an amateur in the Programming world, would experiment with your answer and hopefully it works for me. I appreciate your effort